# Characterization of A based on a decomposition of AA^t in terms of orthogonal matrices and a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

We know that $AA^T = O^T\Lambda O$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$ and diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. Why is it true that $A = O^T \Lambda^{1/2} U$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$?

Comment: I think this follows from the existence of singular value decomposition (at least if the entries of $\Lambda$ are positive and distinct): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate?

Comment: SVD tells you that $A = U^T DV$ for a diagonal matrix $D$ with non-negative diagonal entries and two orthogonal matrices $U, V$. This gives $AA^T = U^T D^2 U$. If the entries of $D^2$ are positive and distinct then the columns of $U$ are unique up to multiplication by $\pm 1$ so after possibly multiplying the columns of $U$ by appropriate signs (which also requires multiplying the columns of $V$ by appropriate signs) you get $U = O$.